# XSLT - Remove HTML tags (except those whitelisted) but keep content

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to have all HTML tags removed except some that are whitelisted but the content should remain.
For example:

```
<root>
  <item>
  &lt;p&gt;&lt;img height="269" alt="" hspace="5" src="[some src]" width="200"    align="right" /&gt;Sample TEXT &lt;strong&gt;Sample text&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;em&gt;Sample  text text text&lt;/em&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
  </item>
</root>
```

I want in the example above to delete all HTML formatting but keep the strong tag and all the text information should remain. So the code will be transformed to something like this:

```
<root>
  <item>
  Sample TEXT &lt;strong&gt;Sample text&lt;/strong&gt; Sample  text text text
  </item>
</root>
```

What will xslt (**version 1.0**) look like for this purpose?

Comment: note for future: it would be better if you formatted the code as code, which will make it easier for us to read

Comment: An XSLT is not going to work here because the HTML you want to process is encoded.  The XSLT will just see it as a single, big string.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you want to use? Some like Saxon 9 have extensions to parse fragments of XML or HTML http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html respectively XSLT 3.0 has http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/fn/parse-xml.

Comment: @MartinHonnen
1.0
    `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: @David
If we assign it without output escaping to a variable and then parse this variable in some way ?..
    `<xsl:variable name="htmlToParse">
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="root/item"/>
</xsl:variable>`

$htmlToParse - will it be still just a string?

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` is a serialization feature applied on final result trees, it doesn't work within a variable. Which XSLT processor do you use? You will need to check whether it provides an extension function to parse a string with markup into nodes or whether it easily allows you to implement one.